# distinguishing between motherboard problems or cpu failure

Tags: cpu, motherboard

my pc is not booting. After looking at some of the answers on this site I removed the hard drive( SAMSUNG HD161HJ) and removed the RAM chip. Upon powering it up it did not beep and the monitor also gave the no signal message. I have thus realized it could be either:

1. Failure of motherboard
2. microprocessor failure

My question is how to know which of the two are the issue in this case? and if its the motherboard what makes sense: replacing the entire thing or the more old school approach of taking it upon myself to go all hardware techie and fix it on my own.

Comment: I would suggest you find a friend or a friend of a friend. Or even a friend of an enemy, who has done simple PC diagnostics and might have a few spare components floating around. If you know what you are doing you must test your mother board with another Power Supply and possibly with another CPU. While the PSU is simple to test. Plugging another CPU in is not. There are of course many speeds and socket types of CPU that make life difficult. So bottom line. Phone a friend to help.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this ..

Unplug your external power (AC) first ..

Unplug your ATX power socket (from Power supply to mainboard) and 4 pin power socket too

Uninstall (take up) the processor and put it back ..

Plug the ATX power socket and the 4 pins too .. and plug your external power

Uninstall your RAM chips

Turn on your PC and listen .. is there any beep ?, If theres no beep so some failure in 
Mainboard or powersupply

**Be careful, better do this with someone knows about PC ...**